# git shortlog: how to exclude "(cherry picked from commit ____)" blah?

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-log

`git shortlog` is handy for making a human-readable summary of changes. However, when I cherry-pick changes from the master branch I use the `-x` flag to `git cherry-pick` because it records which commit it picked from. This causes some ugliness in the shortlog:

```
% git shortlog Version-3.5.3..3.5

Dan S (5):
  Fix typo that causes build fail on big-endian archs, thanks Felipe Sateler     (cherry picked from commit 4588258193072cd2fb845f7fb0b4670d6ad5edf2)
  fix build on ARM (where qreal==float); thanks Felipe Sateler     (cherry picked from commit 976d560060185c1e31c9f40660172f0054a4a05c)
  Strip gremlin characters from JITLib wrapForNodeProxy.sc     (cherry picked from commit d0842acae77a90b5eb9811d947ee2dad2282edff)
  choose clipping rather than wraparound for writing integer-format audio     files (libsndfile setting)
  arm build fix: another double->qreal in QcMultiSlider     (cherry picked from commit 548ad319dddf53e4edac1cfa44b3193027eefda2)
```

Is there an easy way to tell `git shortlog` that we don't want those cherry-pick lines (which are on new lines in the actual log)?

Of course, I know it's possible to filter them out, for example using `git shortlog Version-3.5.3..3.5 | sed 's/[(]cherry picked.*$//g'`. But it seems that git should be aware of its own annotations and be able to deal with them. Anything I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to tell git shortlog that we don't want those
>   cherry-pick lines (which are on new lines in the actual log)?

Currently, there is no easy way to do it with `git shortlog` alone.

These cherry-pick lines are added on the second lines of the commit message, so they are considered a part of the commit title by most of the git tools. As Vince suggested, one can try to provide a custom format for shortlog entries (with `--format` option), however, there seems to be no such pretty-formats or format placeholders that would return only the first line of the subject. (see `man git log`)

> But it seems that git should be aware of its own annotations and be
>   able to deal with them. Anything I've missed?

`git shortlog` actually seems to be aware only of `[PATCH]` prefixes (precisely, in terms of regexp: `^\s*\[PATCH[^]]*\]`).

To sum up, I think that the best would be to stay with your `sed` substitution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the --pretty argument, it's pretty useful if you need to scan a lot of log:

http://gitimmersion.com/lab_10.html

I remember I saw a very extensive resource about it in the past but I can't find it any more. Anyway if this one is not enough, search further.